# How to prevent accessing secure cross-domain data store

Tags: web-application, json

I have a client that needs to be able to secure a data site from hackers.  This is the methodology we currently are looking at:

**server.com** (web server) —> HTTP JSON API request —> **dataStore.net** (data server).

He doesn’t want to force people to authenticate just to visit **server.com**.  Authentication would be needed just for accessing **dataStore.net**.  The cross-domain javascript call is possible via CORS, but CORS is not security.

I need to prevent:  **some-person.com** —> HTTP JSON API request —> **dataStore.net**

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: why can the datastore not simply check if the request comes from a whitelisted IP? if it doesn't, log and deny.

Comment: That means the user has to register, something the client doesn't want them to have to "authenticate" at the web server.

Comment: so you want someperson to be able to access datastore only after they've gotten a link from server? I thought you were doing a curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Please bear in mind my answer is based on assumptions. If you edit your question to clarify let me know and I'll update my answer.*

From your diagram

> server.com (web server) —> HTTP JSON API request —> dataStore.net (data server).

it appears that you are connecting to `datastore.net` from your server.

However, as you mention CORS, I get the impression that the following diagrams are more accurate:

`user —> HTTP request —> server.com`

`user -> HTTP JSON API request —> datastore.net`

?

> Authentication would be needed just for accessing dataStore.net.

This statement adds further weight to my assumption.

If this is the case then your authentication needs to take place on `datastore.net` (not `server.com`). Only authenticated requests should be allowed to access the data on `datastore.net`. You also mention that you do not wish for users to register. If you want to protect your data on `datastore.net` then you must only allow authenticated users to connect, which is why registration is actually neccessary.

The other option is to only allow `server.com` to communicate with `datastore.net` (first diagram) - i.e. server side access to the API. This means that `datastore.net` is effectively a back-end server and does not need to be visible on the internet at all (for inbound traffic other than from `server.com`).

Comment: question updated: changed dataStore.com to dataStore.net

Comment: @spokane-dude: OK, how about my assumptions?

Comment: They are correct... the user makes a request from server.com which in turn makes a JSON API request to dataStore.net.

Comment: @spokane-dude: I think you should take your `datastore.net` API off the internet and simply have a direct back-end connection to it from `server.com`.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to prevent: some-person.com —> HTTP JSON API request —>
>   dataStore.net

It is important to understand, that if anyone wants to get data from your data store they could just use any web proxy to circumvent cross origin policies.

It is unclear what you are asking here, but I would recommend to take dataStore.net off the internet, put it in a private network and let server.com back-end talk to it through internal network. Alternatively if it needs to be on the internet you could let server.com back-end to authenticate and deny any other requests.

This way users can still user server.com without registering, but your data store will be protected.